# Getting input from dialog in an MVC architecture

Tags: java, swing, oop, model-view-controller

I'm using Java with Swing and was wonder if there was a best practice concerning getting input from a dialog. I'm using a MVC architecture and I'm unsure whether it should be done from the model, the view, or the controller.

Comment: Controller is the responsible for ask the view for the input text

Comment: View is the layer that gets the inputs from user and pass them to the Controller. If you're using Swing, user wll fill the JTextFields values in the window [View], for example, and on pressing the submit button the Controller must be provided with those values to process them and decide the next step [Controller]

Comment: Information coming from the user should "probably" be done from the view itself, but then raises some questions about context. It's not unreasonable to consider that the view, through some event, would ask the controller for more information, in which case it would present a dialog to the user (possibly via another controller/view) and then return that information to the original view

Comment: @Jason Queen Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Java with Swing and was wonder if there was a best practice concerning getting input from a dialog. I'm using a MVC architecture and I'm unsure whether it should be done from the model, the view, or the controller.

At the first look, all 3 classes (model, view and controller) seems possible to handle the input .

However if we think about the roles and responsibilities of each class, it wouldn't be hard to decide which is the suitable class to take the input.

**Model**: Holds your data and methods which handle your data

**View**: The User Interface

**Controller**: A coordinator between Model and View

---

[image]

Using the most simplistic example to elaborate the idea; A program which receives a number (with JOptionPane) and display a message on whether it is `odd` or `even` (via JOptionPane).

## The Model

Model is responsible for holding the data, and some methods to work with the data:

```
class MyModel
{
    private String outcome;
    
    public void checkEvenOdd(int number){
        if(number % 2 == 0)
            outcome = "even";
        else
            outcome = "odd";    
    }
    
    public String getOutcome(){
        return outcome;
    }
}
```

After all, the **model** is only responsible for holding the data and the logic, hence it will leave the job of getting the data to someone else.

---

## The View

View is the interface which the user will be interacting with.

```
class MyView
{
    public int promptNumber(){
        int num = 0;
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to test whether it is even or odd.");
        if(s.matches("\\d+"))  //if is numeric
            num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Numeric input required.");
        
        return num;                 
    }
    
    public void displayResult(String result){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result, "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }   
}
```

The view will not hold the data, neither will it perform any calculations or logic implementation. It is only responsible for ***interacting*** with the user. See the word "interacting"? Yes, we will get the input with the View class. But it won't pass the input to the Model directly, because in MVC, the View and the Model does not know the existence of each other.

---

## The Controller

Since Model and View do not interact with each other, we need a coordinator to coordinate both classes (model and view).

```
class MyController
{
    private MyModel model;  
    private MyView view;


    public MyController(MyModel model, MyView view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;       
    }
    
    public void start(){
        int num = view.promptNumber();
        model.checkEvenOdd(num);
        view.displayResult(model.getOutcome());     
    }
}
```

The Controller will ask the View to interact with the user which receive an input if an input is given.

The input is then passed to Model for processing. Model will pass the processed result back to Controller.

The Controller will finally pass the result to View to be displayed to the user.

---

## Running the example:

To drive the example, we create an instance of them and run the program:

```
class MVCExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        MyView view = new MyView();
        MyController controller = new MyController(model, view);                
        controller.start();
    }
}
```

---

## The Conclusion

> I'm unsure whether it should be done from the model, the view, or the controller.

If we think logically on the roles and responsibilities of each class (Model, View & Controller), I would say **View** will be responsible to receive the input. This applies for a console or Swing program as well.